# Measuring Email Send Speed

Tags: marketing-cloud, send-email, data-views

The Trailblazer "Email Send Speed Optimization" section does a fine job explaining WHAT send speed is and what to consider, but it doesn't explain HOW to measure send speed.

Is the speed simply the difference between "PickupTime" vs. "DeliveredTime" on the _Job Data View?

Ref: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/email-send-speed-optimization/measure-send-speed

Comment: Just to consider that _Job DV can have "PickupTime" and "DeliveredTime" fields empty and also those fields will contain time value up to the minute but no seconds, that is why for some sends your formula will not be resolved.

Comment: Adding to this, Journey (triggered sends) will not have a DeliveredTime when the Journey is still active as in theory the job is not delivered yet. Another option is to go into the _Send DV and check MIN(EventDate) and MAX(EventDate) by JobId. This will also have its flaws as there are several factors which can slow down the speed